# Grouping similar values in a df for yahoo finance

Tags: python, list, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a a df that looks like this (although it extends to the whole SP500):

```
        Sector
Symbol
MMM     XLI
ABT     XLV
ABBV    XLV
ACN     XLK
ATVI    XLK
```

My question is, how can I group the symbols together based on sectors? Eg, when I want to access the data, i want to have all symbols grouped by sector.

So far I have tried:

```
sector_list = list(df[df['Sector']=='XLV'].index)
```

This works, but only works for ONE sector at a time. I want to calculate returns of all 10 sectors at the same time, so I need an equation that can return ALL of them at once, grouped by sector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` and convert all index values to `list`:

```
s = df.groupby('Sector').apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())
print (s)
Sector
XLI          [MMM]
XLK    [ACN, ATVI]
XLV    [ABT, ABBV]
dtype: object
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column `Symbol` from index values and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Sector` and create `list` from column `Symbol` per group by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
s = df.reset_index().groupby('Sector')['Symbol'].apply(list)
print(s)
Sector
XLI          [MMM]
XLK    [ACN, ATVI]
XLV    [ABT, ABBV]
Name: Symbol, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second one

Comment: so what exactly is going on here? you reset the index, group the symbols by sector, and make them a list? why do you need apply here

Comment: Thanks, when I try to put in get_data_yahoo, yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo(s[['XLB','XLE']],start,end)                                                  ,  I get the following error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'
Do you know why?

Comment: What is desired output from `s[['XLB','XLE']]` ?

Comment: getting stock data for all stocks in XLB and XLE

Comment: It is a bit complicated. Do you need for `['XLV','XLK']` output `[['ACN', 'ATVI'], ['ABT', 'ABBV']]` ?

Comment: then need `data = s.loc[['XLV','XLK']].values.tolist()` `print (data)`, because need select rows

Comment: now it says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: I think error is in `get_data_yahoo` function. Is possible use parameter as nested list? `yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo([['ACN', 'ATVI'], ['ABT', 'ABBV']],start,end)` ?

Comment: but if need `['ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ATVI']` then solution is `data = np.concatenate(s.loc[['XLV','XLK']].values).tolist()`. But maybe it works only with one value like  `yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo('ABT',start,end)`

Comment: I never work with `get_data_yahoo`, so it is hard to advice you how best use this function.